# Use Websockets with secure connection on Express Server + Elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to integrate WebSockets into my application. The backend is a simple express server and on the front end, we are using React. The socket connection works completely correctly locally on WS but after deployment, it does not work using protocol WSS. I get an error socket is closed.

The deployment is done using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The HTTPS and WSS connections are on the same port and the HTTPS connection is still working fine. It's only the web sockets that are not working. I am not familiar with deployment stuff and have been trying to get this work for 2 days tried all solutions I could find online but nothing works. How can I fix this? Please help. If there is a workaround possible please let me know that too.

I saw in the load balancer we only have HTTPS and HTTPS listeners but there is no option to add a WSS listener. The load balancer is of type application. I can add a TCP listener in the network load balancer but then that one does not have one for HTTPS.

I tried adding a rule in the load balancer for the WS path pattern as listed online but that did not work either. I do not want to mess with the configuration too much and end up ruining the HTTPS that is working right now.

I cannot modify HTTPS to TCP or vice versa as I read in other posts only create new load balancers.

Some of the options listed in online answers to remove the proxy server cannot find them on the AWS console. On the free version of AWS.